# Convergence in distribution of random sums of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, central-limit-theorem

I have been working on the following exercise:

Let $\{X_{k}\}_{k\geq 1}$ be i.i.d. random variables and let $\{\xi_{n}\}_{n\geq 1}$ be Poisson random variables with $\xi_{n}\in Po(n)$. Assume further that the $X_{k}$ and the $\xi_{n}$ are independent of each other.

Compute the characteristic function of $Z_{n}$ where

$$Z_{n}:=\sum_{k=1}^{\xi_{n}}X_{k}$$

Then, assuming that $\mathbb{E}X_{1}=0$ and $\mathbb{E}X_{1}^{2}=1$ prove that the sequence $Z/\sqrt{n}$ converges in distribution.

I was able to prove that $\phi_{Z_{n}}(t)=e^{n(\phi_{X_{1}}(t)-1)}$ without too much difficulty. As each $Z_{n}$ ``looks like" the sum of the first $n$ of the $X_{k}$ I would expect that $Z_{n}/\sqrt{n}$ converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$. The first part of the exercise would suggest that the Levy continuity theorem is to be used. Operating with the belief that $\phi_{Z_{n}}(t/\sqrt{n})$ converges to $e^{(-1/2)t^{2}}$ we would have that

$$\phi_{Z_{n}}(t/\sqrt{n})=e^{n(\phi_{X_{1}}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}\right)-1)}\rightarrow e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^{2}}$$

However I have been unable to prove this convergence. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think that you should be proving that $\phi_{\frac{Z_n}{\sqrt{N}}}(t) \to e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}$ surely

Comment: Did you mean to type $\phi_{Z_{n}/\sqrt{n}}(t)$? This is the same as $\phi_{Z_{n}}(t/\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: yes exactly, and ok yes i see your point. It seems like L'hopitals could be useful here

Comment: Yep, have a go with using L'Hopitals rule twice on the limit $n(\phi_{X_{1}}(\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}})-1)$. Use the $n$ as a denominator of $1/n$.

Comment: Presumably you are differentiating with respect to $n$? Or are you making a substitution? In either event one has to differentiate $\phi_{X_{1}}(t/\sqrt{n})$ with respect to $n$ in some sense, which I don't see how to do.

Comment: yes that's exactly right. Well you can different that expression and leave it as $-tn^{-3/2} \phi'_{X_1}(t/\sqrt{n})$. If you do L'hopitals again, you should find the powers on $n$ in front will cancel out and you'd be left with $\lim_{n \to \infty} \phi''_{X_1}(t/\sqrt(n)) = \phi''(0)=-1$, obviously with a coefficient of $t^{2}$

Comment: $\phi''(t/\sqrt{n}) = \mathbb{E}[i^2 X_1^2 e^{i\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}X_1}]$

Comment: differentiating $-\frac{1}{2}tn^{-3/2}\phi_{X_{1}}^{\prime}(t/\sqrt{n})$ gives me $\frac{1}{4}t^{2}n^{-3}\phi^{\prime\prime}_{X_{1}}(t/\sqrt{n})+\phi_{X_{1}}^{\prime}(t/\sqrt{n})\frac{3}{4}tn^{-5/2}$. While the power of $n$ on the first term will cancel, the second one will not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95161/discussion-between-robert-thingum-and-george-dewhirst).

Comment: Interesting question and wonderful answer!